# JSch BufferedReader Not returning Null

Tags: java, jsch

I am writing an SFTP client that is downloading messages from an SFTP server but  an IO exception being thrown. When I debug the code I see that the code is reading each line and displaying them fine in the console. At the last line it should be null or an extra line feed character, the code should exit the while but I think it is not and that is where the IO exception is coming from.

```
Vector<ChannelSftp.LsEntry> list = ((ChannelSftp) channel).ls("*.*");
System.out.printf("Found %d files in dir %s%n", list.size(), "/Export_ADT/TEST");

for (ChannelSftp.LsEntry file : list) {
    if (file.getAttrs().isDir()) {
        continue;
    }

    System.out.printf("Reading file : %s%n", file.getFilename());
    BufferedReader bis = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sftpChannel.get(file.getFilename())));
    String line = null;
    while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    bis.close();
}

channel.disconnect();
session.disconnect();
```

Comment: Please check on which line exactly the IOException is coming. Is it really coming at `while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null) {`?

Comment: its coming from the while ((line = bis.readLine()) != null),  in the console it prints the last line.